# Wifi is unstable - mt7921e on Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, wireless, mediatek

### Problem description

The wifi connection is very unstable, it always connects, works for some minutes, disconnects, and then repeats. Furthermore when this laptop loses connection, some other devices in the same wifi also disconnect (although they usually work fine, except when this laptop is disconnecting). I've also tested it with a different wifi with the same results.

The error on disconnecting is `14=MIC_FAILURE`, the error when reconnecting (sometimes) fails is `authentication with ... timed out`.

### System running

A new laptop with fresh install.

- OS: Ubuntu 21.10
- Linux Kernel: 5.13.0-35-generic
- Laptop: Lenovo IdeaPad 5 15ALC 82LN0048GE
- Driver: mt7921e

### Attempted solutions

- disable IPv6 in WIFI connection settings
- disable power management (`sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 power off` and `sudo sed -i 's/3/2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`)
- set BSSID (`34:2C:C4:2C:D0:33`) and MAC Address (`4C:D5:77:0A:54:71`) in wifi configuration
- set regulatory domain (`sudo iw reg set AT`)
- using `iwd` instaed of `wpa_supplicant` (https://superuser.com/a/1616266)

### Ideas I didn't get working

I tried to disable 802.11n but didn't find out how to do it for mt7921e.

With `echo "options mt7921e 11n_disable=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/mt7921e.conf` I get in dmesg `[    1.814646] mt7921e: unknown parameter '11n_disable' ignored`.
Also `sudo iwconfig wlp1s0 modu 11g` yields `SET failed on device wlp1s0 ; Operation not supported.`)

### Command outputs

- `ping -s 1 -i 5 -D 1.1.1.1`

```
--- 1.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
763 packets transmitted, 471 received, +52 errors, 38.27% packet loss, time 3842101ms
```

- `lspci | grep Network`

```
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
```

- `sudo lshw -C network` ([paste bin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KkvBrBQRfr/))
- `sudo dmesg` ([paste bin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/kbbkCtRzrT/))
- `sudo dmesg` with iwd instead of wpa_applicants ([paste bin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/Y7CFNqz3gB/))
- `journalctl | grep -E '(wpa_supplicant|NetworkManager|wlp1s0)'` ([paste bin](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G8NV3ck66W/))

Comment: Change wifi router settings so it isn't using TKIP encryption

Comment: I've changed my router settings to only use WPA2-PSK instead of WPA-PSK/WPA2-PSK and it works now